# Cannot Split Malaria Dataset using Tensorflow Datasets

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am following the the [Transfer Learning Tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/images/transfer_learning.ipynb). The notebook successfully runs using the Cats and Dogs Dataset but when I change it to malaria dataset it throws an Assertion Error

```
AssertionError: Unrecognized instruction format: NamedSplit('train')(tfds.percent[0:80])
```

I tried manually splitting it

```
raw_train = tfds.load("malaria", split="train[:80%]")
raw_test = tfds.load("malaria", split="train[81%:90%]")
raw_validation = tfds.load("malaria", split="train[91%:]")
```

But then this throws an error while plotting

```
image, label = raw_train.take(2)
print(b)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(a)
```

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the tutorial with the following code and it worked:

```
(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
'malaria',
split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
with_info=True,
as_supervised=True,)
```

Maybe if you could post the code you used we can compare.

Answer (score 1):

@dulo Collins posted the correct answer. This is a small extension of his answer.

I came across this post while troubleshooting, but I couldn't implement its solution - I didn't know what was causing the problem. Luckily, I found an article that walked through it. This answer is a brief overview of the problem and solution from that article.

[AssertionError: Unrecognized instruction format: NamedSplit is reported in the TensorFlow official tutorial imdb movie evaluation example](https://www.mscto.com/ai/288109.html)

**Problem**:

Caused by the format of the split data. The error went away after reformatting it.

```
SPLIT_WEIGHTS = (8, 1, 1)

splits = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(weighted=SPLIT_WEIGHTS)

(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', split=list(splits), with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

get_label_name = metadata.features['label'].int2str

for image, label in raw_train.take(2):
  plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(image)
  plt.title(get_label_name(label))
```

The code above is from a [Jupyter Notebook on Tensorflow](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/notebooks/CS231N_TensorFlow_Tutorial.ipynb) in [Stanford's CS231n course](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/syllabus.html).

**Error**:

AssertionError: Unrecognized instruction format: NamedSplit('train')(tfds.percent[0:80])

**Solution**:

```
splits = ("train[:80]", "train[:10]", "train[:10]")

(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', split=splits, with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

get_label_name = metadata.features['label'].int2str

for image, label in raw_train.take(2):
  plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(image)
  plt.title(get_label_name(label))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. This simple line works for me.

```
(cat_train, cat_valid, cat_test), info = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'], with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```